# Problem with subsription on action and runing cypress code

Tags: typescript, cypress, ngxs

Me and my teammates stuck with e2e test and action in NgXS.
Because we start to fight against wait problem we wanted to subscribe into action which are dispatched to store. Then according to their state we would run or wait with test.
We connected actions into window global object (to make them accesible for store) and subscribe for one action. Yet cypress runner dont run code that we implemented in it. No matter what i do (we used,then try to use chainable even accesing it throu cy.window().invoke()).
There was no response. We are in pinch and i will not lie. I would gladly welcome any ideas what is wrong and how make it working.

```
  cy.window().its('Cypress').its('actions$')
    .then(action$ => {
      action$.pipe(ofActionCompleted(gridAction.LazyLoadSetup)) // gridAction.lazyLoadSetup is action 
subscribe(rez => {
          cy.log(rez); // this is not runned
          console.log(rez) // this is running correctly
        });
    });
```